# Removing space with awk when appending value from 1 txt file to another one?

Tags: linux, unix

I have 2 text files. "A.txt" contains

```
A 1 AB ... 1 5 -3 4.5 (contains 11 columns. So "4.5" is in the 11th column)
A 2 BC ... -2 3 8 9.2
A 3 WE ... 2 3 8 5.2
A 4 RT ...  23 2 24 4.1 
...
END
```

"B.txt" is similar except that the final 2 columns differ from that of "A.txt". Another difference is that "B.txt" contains some additional lines not in "A.txt". For example, the third line `A 3 QEW ... 5 23 34 5` is in "B.txt" but not in "A.txt"

```
A 1 AB ... 1 5 4 9
A 2 BC ... -2 3 1 0
A 3 QEW ... 5 23 34 5
A 4 WE ... 2 3 -7 56
A 5 RT ...  23 2 -5 14 
...
END
```

What I want to do is extract the value of the last column in each line of "A.txt" and append it to the corresponding line in "B.txt". And for each line in "B.txt" that is not in "A.txt", I want to append the value 1 if the 3rd column element begins with the letter "Q" (for example, QEW) and the value 2 otherwise. So the output should look like

```
A 1 AB ... 1 5 4 9 4.5
A 2 BC ... -2 3 1 0 9.2
A 3 QEW ... 5 23 34 5 1 
A 4 WE ... 2 3 -7 56 5.2
A 5 RT ...  23 2 -5 14 4.1
...
END
```

The `awk` commands below works:

```
NR==FNR{
    arr[$3] = $11
    next
}
{
    if ($3 in arr){
        print($0, arr[$3])
    }else if ($3 == "^Q"){
        print($0, "2")
    }else{
        print($0, "1")
    }
}
```

Ran with

```
awk -f script.awk f1 f2
```

The only problem is that the output I get is

```
A 1 AB ... 1 5 4 9
 4.5
A 2 BC ... -2 3 1 0
 9.2
A 3 QEW ... 5 23 34 5
 1
A 4 WE ... 2 3 -7 56
 5.2
A 5 RT ...  23 2 -5 14
 4.1
...
END
```

which is wrong because the values in the last column should be entered in new lines like that. How can I fix this? Is there another commands I can use instead of what I listed?

Answer (score 0):

Your code and spec doesn't match for Q, anyway, here is a script that works

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$NF; next}
       $3 in a{print $0, a[$3]; next} 
              {print $0, ($3~/^Q/)?1:2}' f1 f2
```

print is usually written not as a function, more idiomatic is `print $0,1`  Also no need to quote 1 and 2.

Comment: when I try this I still get the newline problem I mentioned in the original question